# How do i display one item at a time in a very big xml file with the previous item or next item in MVC

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4

XML file is big and rarely change.

I have PageA that will filter some items out of that XML file then it will display the rest in a partial view _PageB. I want to display only one item at a time with ability to go back and next item in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: You can load the entire xml in memry? Or you need to open the xml with randomic access?

Comment: well, I'm learning, so both.

Comment: Paging. On the server side, you can load the xml into a list where each element is a record from the xml file. Then your page will request data with some parameters (e.g. page, page size), then your logic could do something like list.Skip(pageSize * page).Take(pageSize) and return that to the page. In this case your page size is 1. Or you could do the same thing on the client side but you'd have to load the entire thing into memory which could be bad news.

Comment: You could do something in the middle where the first request sends back a subset of the larger file (filtered data), then load that into memory (the browser via js object). Using javascript paging to page back and forth through that data. But each time you update the filter, it'll have to go back to the server to get the new subset. That should be a decent balance of server side and client side processing.

Comment: What if the filtered data is still a consider amount?  Would trying to put it in js object cause a delay in loading the page?